# Facelifting XClock while using Xrender: A long and winding road

Tags: x-resources

Basically, `xclock` is a great tool, and every basic X setup would have it "onboard". However, *configuring* `xclock` (analog) *while* keeping `XRender` active is definitely not for the faint of heart. In particular, beginners will not have any chance to configure the *analog* clock without delving deeply into the `.Xresource` realm, since everything you set at the command line will be *for the non-rendered mode only* (requires option `-norender`) and ignored by default (which means, that `XRender` is being used). Plus, the documentation about it is abysmal, and examples which actually *deal* with `XRender` are rare as hen's teeth. Hence, I decided to start my own approach.
I wish there was an easier way to do all this, but there apparently isn't.
For one, this question will probably help new users as a guide how to set things up for "their" `xclock`; on the other hand, I'd also like to ask you guys if there is any way to improve my "configuration file" (mind the quotes).
Oddly enough, `.Xresources` is widely deemed "obsolete" and "last century", but what if the application you use *does* rely on the old-fashioned way, using `xrdb`, `.Xresources` and the whole caboodle?

I personally fancied a *"**night design**"* because it fit perfectly to my desktop style. So this is what I did:

```
$ touch ~/.Xresources
$ vi ~/.Xresources

XClock*foreground: #fbfbfb
XClock*background: #000018
XClock*update: 1
XClock*geometry:          210x210+1020+12
XClock.Clock.majorColor:  rgba:f0/f0/19/7b
XClock.Clock.minorColor:  rgba:a0/c0/f0/c0
XClock.Clock.hourColor:   rgba:c9/66/11/72
XClock.Clock.minuteColor: rgba:00/82/9f/72
XClock.Clock.secondColor: rgba:50/93/30/6f
```

`rgba` stands for "red, green, blue, alpha" - where the fourth parameter,  *alpha*, will indicate the opacity level in hexadecimal notation:  a `00` will make the clock hand or tick mark invisible; a `ff` will turn any opacity off.
So far, so good. Since we do not want to restart the `X` server for these things to come into effect, we will simply merge our settings into those that may (or, as usual, may not) be already there:

```
$ xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources && xclock &
```

Although I hate to brag, I honestly think it looks *way* better than the boring design which is default on my desktop.

But during my efforts in getting this to work the way I wanted to, there has also a question come up from my side:
I actually "stole" the syntax `XClock.Clock.<parameter>` from the following resource file:

`/etc/X11/app-defaults/XClock-color`

Interestingly enough, ALL of those parameters which end in `...Color` require the same `XClock.`**Clock**`.<parameter>` syntax as in `app-defaults`; e. g. `XClock*hourColor: rgba:ff/ff/ff/80` will NOT get the hour hand white, nor set the opacity to `0x80`.

Why is that so?
Up to now, I thought the `*` was simply a wildcard meaning `XClock<whatever><parameter>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. A resource specification using `*` is a wildcard. Your issue here is because of the fact that you probably have **both** an `XClock*` and an `XClock.Clock` specifications in your presently loaded resources database. In this instance it will prefer the explicit entries to the wildcard ones. You can see what you presently have set in your resource database for your XClock with `appres XClock`:

```
 appres XClock
 XClock.input:   false
```

If I create a resource file with wildcard resources:

```
XClock*foreground: #fbfbfb
XClock*background: #000018
XClock*update: 1            
XClock*geometry:          210x210+1020+12
XClock*majorColor:  rgba:f0/f0/19/7b
XClock*minorColor:  rgba:a0/c0/f0/c0
XClock*hourColor:   rgba:c9/66/11/72
XClock*minuteColor: rgba:00/82/9f/72
XClock*secondColor: rgba:50/93/30/6f
```

And then use a load them with a `xrdb -merge xclock` operation, `appres XClock` now shows:

```
$ appres XClock
XClock*secondColor:     rgba:50/93/30/6f
XClock*foreground:      #fbfbfb
XClock*hourColor:       rgba:c9/66/11/72
XClock*update:  1
XClock*background:      #000018
XClock*geometry:        210x210+1020+12
XClock*majorColor:      rgba:f0/f0/19/7b
XClock*minorColor:      rgba:a0/c0/f0/c0
XClock.input:   false
XClock*minuteColor:     rgba:00/82/9f/72
```

If I start up xclock, I get your nice shiny "nightime" theme. Now if I were to edit that resource file and replace the wildcard resources with explicit resources (note `!` is a comment line):

```
XClock*foreground: #fbfbfb
XClock*background: #000018
XClock*update: 1
XClock*geometry:          210x210+1020+12
XClock.Clock.majorColor:  rgba:f0/f0/19/ff
XClock.Clock.minorColor:  rgba:a0/c0/f0/ff
XClock.Clock.hourColor:   rgba:c9/66/11/ff
XClock.Clock.minuteColor: rgba:00/82/9f/ff
XClock.Clock.secondColor: rgba:50/93/30/ff
!XClock*majorColor:  rgba:f0/f0/19/7b
!XClock*minorColor:  rgba:a0/c0/f0/c0
!XClock*hourColor:   rgba:c9/66/11/72
!XClock*minuteColor: rgba:00/82/9f/72
!XClock*secondColor: rgba:50/93/30/6f
```

and merge the resource file again with an `xrdb -merge xclock`, `appres XClock` now shows:

```
XClock.Clock.secondColor:       rgba:50/93/30/ff
XClock.Clock.minorColor:        rgba:a0/c0/f0/ff
XClock.Clock.hourColor: rgba:c9/66/11/ff
XClock.Clock.minuteColor:       rgba:00/82/9f/ff
XClock.Clock.majorColor:        rgba:f0/f0/19/ff
XClock*secondColor:     rgba:50/93/30/6f
XClock*foreground:      #fbfbfb
XClock*hourColor:       rgba:c9/66/11/72
XClock*update:  1
XClock*background:      #000018
XClock*geometry:        210x210+1020+12
XClock*majorColor:      rgba:f0/f0/19/7b
XClock*minorColor:      rgba:a0/c0/f0/c0
XClock*minuteColor:     rgba:00/82/9f/72
XClock.input:   false
```

Note how *both* explicit and wildcard resources are listed against the XClock class. In this instance `xclock` will prefer the explicit resource over the wildcard one, and I get the clock with the non-alpha colours.

To fix the issue use a `-load` operation instead of a `-merge` operation (xrdb defaults to `-load` if you do not supply any options, i.e `xrdb file` is the same as `xrdb -load file`).

This effectively clears your resources database, loads the system defaults and then adds your XClock resource settings in that file. A good trick to know is that you can restore  "system defaults" with `xrdb /dev/null`. You can get a copy of the existing resource database (including system defaults) with: `xrdb -query -all` which can be redirected to a file, and then edited to your tastes.

On most systems putting these in your .Xresources or .Xdefaults will mean they will get loaded when the X session is created, so you don't have to load them manually from X session to X session.

I use wildcards to set most apps to do white on black (I'm not a fan of black on white):

```
*background: #000000
*foreground: #ffffff
```

As to what resources you can set for xclock they are covered in the man page (most X11 commands cover their resources in the man page).

Another thing that is useful to know (and not often documented) is that most X11 commands can be passed `-name` argument which allows you have resources that are separate to the default app settings, so for an example if I were to have:

```
Leary*background: #ff0000
```

as a resource setting and then run xclock with `xclock -name Leary` I will get an xclock with a violent red background. Any explicit/wildcard XClock resources settings are loaded and then they get overriden with ones set by the `Leary` class. I can then use it to apply the same settings to say `xterm`, with `xterm -name Leary`.

There are a number of these "standard" command line options that most X11 commands use:

```
-display host:n
     Location of the X server. 
-geometry wxh+x+y
     Window size and location. 
-bg color
     Window background color. 
-fg color
     Text and graphics color. 
-fn font
    Text font. 
-iconic
    Initial window to be started iconized. 
-title strings
    Window header title.
```

Comment: This was simply AWESOME!! Thank you so much. I've learned a boatload of new things. Besides, I am usually a bit reluctant to that `-load` parameter since, as you say, it will PURGE the entire database, and maybe there was something fancy in there which was needed elsewhere?

Comment: You _might_ purge some settings, but they will have happened from starting the X session (and the system defaults being loaded and your user resources overloaded) and the point you `-load`. You can always dump the existing database with a `-query -all` if you are feeling paranoid, and then after your `-load` do another `-query -all` and `diff` the results.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful, feel free to accept the answer, if nobody comes along with a better answer :)

Comment: Very nice answer! I would add that you can find the same way you can use -name to customize instance, you can also find default value using xprop (the WM_CLASS string is the way to go)

Comment: I just want to comment here, that I really like the XClock color theme that has been used in this example!