# How do I stop xclock restarting at every system startup

Tags: linux-mint, startup, kill

I use Linux Mint on one of my machines. The other day I tried xclock via Terminal command line. I then found I couldn't stop, end or kill it. Or rather I could kill it but it immediately restarted. Every time.

Since then it starts with every system startup, in the middle of the screen, in default colours. I can start a second instance, with any parameters I choose, and successfully kill the new one. But I can't get rid of the old one.

This is driving me mad. How can I remove whatever starts this thing every time?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mint MATE 20.3

I set the xclock colors in this file  (luc is my user name, change accordingly your settings)

```
sudo xed /home/luc/.Xresources
```

I test with

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources && xclock
```

For the immediate restart, sorry I do not know.  Is is in a cron job ?  Check with

```
crontab -l
```

( info from  [Facelifting XClock while using Xrender: A long and winding road](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89304/facelifting-xclock-while-using-xrender-a-long-and-winding-road) )

Comment: Since it was annoying me I gave in and renamed xclock. But I would still love to know if there is a right way to stop it.

Comment: There is surely a way to stop it, but it ask for investigation.  Did you check in the 'control center', the entry 'Applics on start'  ( I translate from French, so the text is approximative, search 'start' )